# iOS: How to get the frame of my UIView just set in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

everyone!
I have added my custom UIView by ***interface builder***.
And in my custom UIView class, I override the `-awakeFromNib` method in which I wanna log out my UIView's Frame.x or Frame.y **set in nib file**.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

PS:Is there anyway to get the frame rect I set in the interface builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view's frame is *not* meaningful until viewWillAppear is called. In my experience, the frame is CGRectZero until then. Keep in mind that in your storyboard, you are working with "simulated metrics"